# Storing results of binomial confidence interval in Stata using by prefix

Tags: stata, confidence-interval, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to calculate the 95% binomial Wilson confidence interval for the proportion of people completing treatment by year (dataset is line-listed for each person).

I want to store the results into a matrix so that I can use the `putexcel` command to export the results to an existing Excel spreadsheet without changing the formatting of the sheet. I have created a binary variable `dscomplete_binary` which is 0 for a person if treatment was not completed, and 1 if treatment was completed.

I have tried the following:

```
bysort year: ci dscomplete_binary, binomial wilson level(95)
```

This gives output of each year with the 95% confidence intervals. Previously I used `statsby` to collapse the dataset to store the results in variables but this clears the dataset from the memory and so I have to constantly re-open it.

Is there a way to run the command and store the results in a tabular format so that the data is stored in a similar way to this:

```
    year     mean        LowerCI     UpperCI
r1  2005    .7031588    .69229454   .71379805
r2  2006    .75532377   .74504232   .7653212
r3  2007    .78125924   .77125096   .79094833
r4  2008    .80014324   .79059798   .80935836
r5  2009    .81860977   .80955398   .82732689
r6  2010    .82641232   .81723672   .83522016
r7  2011    .81854123   .80955547   .82719356
r8  2012    .83497983   .82621944   .8433823
r9  2013    .85411799   .84527379   .86253893
r10 2014    .84461939   .83499599   .85377985
```

I have tried the following commands, which give different estimates to the binomial Wilson option:

```
svyset id2
bysort year: eststo: ci dscomplete_binary, binomial wilson level(95)
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the `statsby:` prefix as suggested by `help ci` rather than `bysort year:`?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I did do that but my problem with the statsby command is that it clears the memory from Stata, which means i would have to reopen it and since the dataset i am using is quite large, this is not very helpful. I want to do this whilst preserving my original dataset so that i can restore it after my ci command.

Comment: How about using `preserve` & `restore` then?

Comment: I can't as when you use the statsby command, it clears the memory of the dataset which is what my problem is.

Comment: @radek's suggestion of using `preserve` and `restore` seems totally sensible to me; it's the purpose of those commands to let you end up with the original data as painlessly as possible. The sequence would be `preserve` -- `statsby` -- `restore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a development of the suggestion already made to use `statsby`. The objections to it are quite puzzling, as it is easy to get back to the original dataset. There is some machine time in re-loading a dataset, but how much personal time has been spent in pursuit of an alternative?

Absent a dataset which we can use, I've provided a reproducible example.

If you wish to do this repeatedly, you'll write a more elaborate program to do it, which is what this forum is all about.

I leave how to export results to Excel as a matter for those so inclined: no details of what is wanted are provided in any case.

```
. sysuse auto, clear 
(1978 Automobile Data)

. preserve 

. statsby mean=r(mean) ub=r(ub) lb=r(lb), by(rep78) : ci foreign, binomial wilson level(95)  
(running ci on estimation sample)

      command:  ci foreign, binomial wilson
         mean:  r(mean)
           ub:  r(ub)
           lb:  r(lb)
           by:  rep78

Statsby groups
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
.....

. list 

     +----------------------------------------+
     | rep78       mean         ub         lb |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |     1          0   .6576198          0 |
  2. |     2          0   .3244076          0 |
  3. |     3         .1   .2562108   .0345999 |
  4. |     4         .5   .7096898   .2903102 |
  5. |     5   .8181818   .9486323   .5230194 |
     +----------------------------------------+

. restore 

. describe
```

The `describe` results will show that we are back where we started.

Comment: I apologize, i had dropped some variables before i entered in preserve, and so when i was trying the statsby command it wouldn't work as it said 'no; data in memory would be lost'.



What i had to do was preserve the raw data and just include extra conditions in the ci command i.e. 

`statsby mean=r(mean) lowerci=(100*(r(lb)),.1)upperci=r(ub), by(year): ci dscomplete_binary if dscohortgroup==0 &  year>2004 & year<2015 , binomial wilson level(95)`

And it worked! I could then restore! Thanks!

Comment: Good that you've understood the small issues. Accepting whichever answer is more helpful would give you some more reputation too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `postfile` family of commands will help you here.  This won't save your data into a matrix, but will save the results of the `ci` command into a new data set, which you name and whose structure you set.  After the analysis is complete, you can load the data saved by `postfile` and export to Excel in the manner of your choosing.

For `postfile`, you analyze the data in a loop instead of using `by` or `bysort`.

Assuming the years in your data run 2005-2014, here is sample code:

```
/*make sure no postfile is open, in case a previous run did not close the file*/
cap postclose ci_results

/*create the postfile that will store results*/
postfile ci_results year mean lowerCI upperCI using ci_results.dta, replace

/*loop through years*/
forval y = 2004/2014 {
    ci dscomplete_binary if year==`y', binomial wilson level(95)
        /*store saved results from ci to postfile.  Make sure the post statement contains results in the same order stated in postfile command.*/
    post (`y') (r(mean)) (r(lb)) (r(ub))
}

/*close the postfile once you've looped through all the cases of interest*/
postclose ci_results
use ci_results.dta, clear
```

Once you load the ci_results.dta data into memory, you can apply any Excel exporting command you like.